# How to verify a file in s3 is downloaded completely in boto3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to download data from s3 and save it as csv format. The format of object in s3 is:

```
s3://<bucketname>/<timestamp>/file
```

when a file is downloaded, it will be writen in a row of '.csv'
Now I need to check if it is completely downloaded so as to I can do some tasks with it.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
keys = bucket.objects.all()
for key in keys:      
    item = key.key.split('/') 
    bucket.download_file(key.key,"db/collecting/" + item[0] + ".csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3r = boto3.resource('s3')
Bucket=s3r.Bucket('bucketname')

for obj in Bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='<timestamp>/'):  # add prefix only if you want objects of a particular subfolder
    filename=obj.key
    key=str(filename)
    local="C://path_to_save-file"
    s3.download_file('bucketname',key, local)
    #your code goes here to use downloaded file
```

you don't need to split *object name or key* , secondly , once your object is downloaded , i.e. completely downloaded , only then it can be used in further code , i.e. only then further code can be implemented otherwise if it is not downloaded completely it will raise an exception which you can easily handle

Answer (score 0):

I would download to a temporary name and then rename when it's done:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
keys = bucket.objects.all()
for key in keys:      
    item = key.key.split('/') 
    bucket.download_file(key.key + ".tmp","db/collecting/" + item[0] + ".csv")
    os.rename(key.key + ".tmp", key.key);
```

In this way during the download any other process would not "see" the file until the rename happens.  If for some reason the download takes a bit longer then you are covered until it is ready.

Comment: From what I can see, boto3 already adds a temporary extension (an arbitrary string of 8 chars) to the files temporarily, serving the same purpose as the ".tmp" would do in the above.